# Creating a list of lists of repeating elements

Tags: list, scheme, racket

this is a homework problem I'm stuck on. I have to create a function in Racket without using explicit recursion or local, that takes in a list of pairs, where the first element of each pair is a non-negative integer, and produces a new list of lists, where each list is k occurrences of the second element in each pair, where k is the first element of each pair. For example (expand-pairs (list (list 1 2) (list 3 4))) would produce (list (list 2) (list 4 4 4))

I got some code working, but only if the second element is a number. Since the question doesn't specify what type of element the second element is, I assume it needs to work for any element. So my function can solve the above example, but can't solve (expand-pairs (list (list 1 'a) (list 3 'b))).

Here is my code:

```
(define (expand-pairs plst) 
  (map 
   (lambda (x) 
     (map 
      (lambda (y) (+ (first (rest x)) y)) 
      (build-list (first x) (lambda (z) (- z z)))))
   plst))
```

My main problem is I don't know how to create a list of length k without using recursion or build-list, but then if I use build-list it creates a list of numbers, and I don't know how to convert that to a list of symbols or any other element.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is a form of [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).  In addition to the answers you receive here, you may the [code samples in Rosetta Code for Run-length encoding](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) enlightening (and there is code for various Lisps (Clojure, Common Lisp, and Scheme)).  The task there is about compressing and decompressing _strings_ (as opposed to lists of lists), but some of the techniques may still be helpful.

Comment: Also, a note about the term “pair”.  In Scheme, _pair_ often means the return value of `cons`, i.e., a dotted pair, a cons-cell.  This is distinct from a list of two elements, which actually requires two cons cells, since `(1 2) == (1 . (2 . ()))`.  I only point this out because based on the specification that the function "takes in a list of pairs", which made the use case `(expand-pairs (list (list 1 2) (list 3 4)))` a little surprising.  It could have been `(expand-pairs (list (cons 1 2) (cons 3 4))) == (expand-pairs '((1 . 2) (3 . 4)))`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another possible implementation, building on @RomanPekar's answer but a bit more idiomatic for Racket:

```
(define (expand-pairs lst)
  (map (lambda (s)
         (build-list (first s) (const (second s))))
       lst))
```

It makes use of the higher-order procedures [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29), [`const`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=const#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._const%29%29) and [`build-list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._build-list%29%29) to create an implementation without using explicit recursion or `local`. The trick here is to understand how the following expression will return `5` copies of `x`:

```
(build-list 5 (const  'x))
            ^    ^     ^
      #copies constant element

=> '(x x x x x)
```

Comment: I'm not at all Racket expert, but looks like using `const` is indeed more Racket-ly here, so +1

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
(define (expand-pairs plst)
  (map (lambda(x) (build-list (car x) (lambda(k) (cadr x)))) plst))
```

You don't have to use `k` in the `build-list`, just take second element of pair.